# INSERT BASE64 FILE INTO ORACLE BLOB USING PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, base64, blob

I’m trying to save images as BLOB on my ORACLE 11g R2 database through the base64 of files uploaded, but when i retrieve this file from DB, it dont show the a image with base64_encode function. And when i dowload this file from SQL Developer, the file doesn’t the image as well, only a message saying that the image is invalid or is corrupted. Details of my problem below:
I have this form in my web page:
[Upload Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JBoD.png)

The “+” button is a file input that when clicked, the user can choose one or more files to upload and these files are showed on a preview, as you can see below:
[Upload Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Vte.png)

The user can open file input, selecet how many images he wants, close file input and re-open it to add more files how many times he wants. For each file added, a javascript create the preview and set the base64 in href of “a” element, as below:

```
    //create preview
$("#exams-fileinput").on('change',function(e){
    var input = $(this);
    var files = input.prop('files');
    var countFiles = files.length;//alert(files.length);

    if (window.File && window.FileReader){ 
        var allow = /png|jpg|jpeg|tiff|pdf$/i;
        // com suporte a FileReader()
        for(i= 0;i <countFiles; i++){                
            file = files[i]; 
            if(!allow.test(file.name)){continue;}
            imageType = /image.*/;
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                filePreview = e.target;
                var fileName    = file.name;
                var fileResult  = filePreview.result;
                var fileThumb   = file.type.match(imageType) ? fileResult : 'assets/img/file-document.png'; // https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/office-20/128/OFFice-51-256.png assets/img/file-document.png
                var classIframe = file.type.match(imageType) ? '' : 'fancybox.iframe';
                var imgPrevContent =  
                        '<div name="file-added" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ms-file-thumbnail-preview-item" >'+ '<a href="'+fileResult+'" class="ms-filedata fancybox '+classIframe+'" rel="exam" data-type="img" data-file-name="'+fileName+'">'+ //<= aqui vai entrar o "fancybox.iframe", se necessário <= Vamos obter daqui o código do arquivo para subir ".ms-filedata"
                                '<figure class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="background-image:url('+fileThumb+');">'+ 

                                    '<figcaption>'+
                                        '<p><i class="fa fa-eye fa-3x"></i><p>'+
                                        '<p class="ms-ellipsis">'+fileName+'</p>'+
                                    '</figcaption>'+
                                '</figure>'+
                            '</a>'+
                            '<input type="file" value="'+fileResult+'" id="" style="display: none;">'+
                        '</div>';

 console.log('Nome do arquivo: '+fileName+' - Tamanho: '+ file.size+' - HTML: '+imgPrevContent.length);
              fileName='';
                $("#exam-view-files").append(imgPrevContent);
            };                
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }            
    }else{ 
        // browser doesn't supor file reader
    }
});
```

When users click on save button “Salvar”, i take all bases64 of files added and sent by ajax to save in a BLOB field in my ORACLE 11g R2 database as below:

```
//save function
$("#btn-save-files").click(function(e){
    var filesToAdd = [];

    $("div[name=file-added]").each(function(e){
        filesToAdd.push({
                           content: $(this).children("a").attr("href"),
                           name: $(this).children("a").data("file-name")
                        });
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'controller/ctrl-person-profile-action.php',
            data: { action: "insertfiles", 
                    files: filesToAdd
                    },
            datatype: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(response){
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                switch(response["status"].toLowerCase()){
                    case "success": swal("Pronto", "Adicionado com sucesso", "success");
                        break;
                    case "fail": swal("Atenção", response["message"], "warning");
                        break;
                    default: swal("Ops..", "Ocorreu um erro inesperado ao inserir o medicamento", "error");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And a take these files and save by PHP, as below:

```
    //Ajax calls this function
function InsertFiles(){
$files = isset($_REQUEST['files']) ? $_REQUEST['files'] : null;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileBase64 = explode(",", explode(";", $file["content"])[1])[1];
    $fileType = explode(":",(explode(";", $file["content"])[0]))[1];

    $fileInsert = new MyFileClass();
    $fileInsert->setFile($fileBase64);
    $fileInsert->setType($fileType);
    $fileInsert->Insert();
}

    //Class MyFile method insert:
public function Insert(){
$sql = "INSERT FILES (ID,
                                                            MIME_TYPE,
                                                            FILE)
                                                            VALUES(SEQ_FILES.NEXTVAL,
                                                            '$this->type,
                                                            EMPTY_BLOB()
) RETURNING FILE INTO :file";

    $conn = GetDBConnection();
    $statment = oci_parse($conn, $sql)

    // Creates an "empty" OCI-Lob object to bind to the locator
    $fileBlob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_DTYPE_LOB);

    // Bind the returned Oracle LOB locator to the PHP LOB object
    oci_bind_by_name($statment, ":file", $fileBlob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);

    // Execute the statement using , OCI_DEFAULT - as a transaction
    oci_execute($statment, OCI_DEFAULT)
        or die ("Erro execute SQL command");

    // Now save a value to the LOB
    if (!$fileBlob->save('INSERT: '.base64_decode($this->file))) {
        // On error, rollback the transaction
        oci_rollback($conn);
        die("Erro execute SQL command");
    } else {
        // On success, commit the transaction
        oci_commit($conn);
    }

    // Free resources
    oci_free_statement($statment);
    $fileBlob->free();
    //feca conexão
    oci_close($conn);
}
```

Can anyone give me some help to save this base64 file into a BLOB field on ORACLE and retrieve a valid file from my BLOB?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by my self just adjusting my insert function, removing 'INSERT: ' string from blob save function, like below:

Before:

```
// Now save a value to the LOB
if (!$fileBlob->save('INSERT: '.base64_decode($this->file))) {
    // On error, rollback the transaction
    oci_rollback($conn);
    die("Erro execute SQL command");
} else {
    // On success, commit the transaction
    oci_commit($conn);
}
```

After:

```
// Now save a value to the LOB
if (!$fileBlob->save(base64_decode($this->file))) {
    // On error, rollback the transaction
    oci_rollback($conn);
    die("Erro execute SQL command");
} else {
    // On success, commit the transaction
    oci_commit($conn);
}
```

Thx again! I hope it can be usefull for someone one day! :)